# struct pointer always getting initialized to nil

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am having this problem where my struct pointer is always getting initialized to `nil` by default. Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct SomeStruct {
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    int array[2];  // If I change this to 1, the code works fine

    struct SomeStruct *ptr;
    printf("%p\n", ptr);  // always prints "nil"
}
```

Can someone please explain what is going on here. Specifically, why does changing the size of array to 1 make the code run fine.

The above was part of some larger code and I was able to simplify the problem to this. I need to use `ptr` later but I get segmentation faults as it is `nil`.

Comment: if you copy this code as-it-is and try with either 1 or 2 like you comment states it will be the same => (nil). your ptr is not set to any value, so it might use garbage values that are on the stack at this time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain what is going on here. Specifically, why does changing the size of array to 1 make the code run fine.

You're using `ptr` without initializing it. Changing the size of the array changes the layout of the stack and your code executes "fine" by luck.

> I need to use ptr later but I get segmentation faults as it is nil

Then assign some memory to it:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Dumbest question I could have asked :(

Comment: rather ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct somestruct));

Comment: @LtWorf I prefer my version, thank you very much as it will still do the right thing if somebody changes the type of `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an uninitialised variable, so you are relying on **undefined behaviour**; the result could be anything.

In practice, you are seeing an artefact of whatever rubbish happens to be on your stack when your program runs.